# Maximum and minimum in a range of independent variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, min

Based on the answer from @Peaceful James, I am attempting to reduce the confusion. Thus, editing the question.

***Edited***

I am trying to find a maximum (and minimum) in the range of an independent variable, i.e. **X**. My code looks like the following. Note, this is just a representative function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import *

X = np.arange(2, 11, 0.2)

Z = np.zeros((len(X),1))

for i in range(0,len(X)):
    Z[i] = 0.1*np.sin(X[i]-5)

print(DataFrame(Z))
A = np.argmax(Z, axis = 0)
B = np.argmin(Z, axis = 0)

C = print("Maximum =",Z[A[0]])
D = print("Minimum =", Z[B[0]])

plt.plot(X,Z,'r-', linewidth = 2)
plt.xlabel('$X$ (-)')
plt.ylabel('$Z$ (-)')
```

1: `A = np.argmax(Z, axis = 0)` the maximum is *0.09995736* (index: (23,0)) which is between the **X** values `6 and 8`.

2: `A = np.argmin(Z, axis = 0)` the min is *-0.09995736* (index: (7,0)) which is between the **X** values `2 and 4`. However, there is another minimum between the **X** values `8 and 10`. I am wondering if there is a way to pass some kind of upper and lower limit values of **X** to `np.argmin` (or to similar command) to get the *second* minimum of function *Z*.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.argsort`:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

```
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(2, 11, 0.2)

Z = np.zeros((len(X),1))

for i in range(0,len(X)):
    Z[i] = 0.1*np.sin(X[i]-5)

C = np.argsort(Z, axis=0)
C = C.flatten()  # flatten because it is currently an array of 1-dim arrays.

print("Maximum =",Z[C[-1]])
print("Second Maximum =",Z[C[-2]])

print("Second Minimum =",Z[C[1]])
print("Minimum =",Z[C[0]])
```

Comment: @ Peaceful James: Thank you for the answer. I have edited my question to point out my exact query. Any input will be appreciated. Thanks again ! :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to hopefully answer your question.